# Embed Image in Email (Outlook client) using SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, outlook

I followed this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adding-images-spd-workflow-emails-larry-saytee/) but Outlook is displaying the image with a red x.

List Column

- Photo = Hyperlink/Picture type

SPD Variables:

- varPhoto = `<IMG SRC="[%Current Item:Photo%]" alt="Test"/>`

The photo URL is https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/library/photo.png
The varPhoto variable is string.

I need to keep the image source dynamic. Also, trust center in Outlook prevents automatic download. Not sure if this causing the image not to show but when I uncheck this option, the image was still coming up as a red x. I also added @sharepointonline.com in the safe sender list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make the image public or place it on another server, like FTP. I couldn’t get the SharePoint image repository working with with emails, I had to place the image somewhere it is available publicly.